# how to replace values in matrix if they have the same beginning?

Tags: r, matrix

I have a big matrix with groceries. 
Some of the values are identical but have different names.
For example:

```
Ketchup  Ketchupwithgarlic  Ketchupspicy Chips Chipsorganic
0               1               0         0      1
1               0               0         0      0
0               0               0         1      0
1               0               0         0      0
```

What I want to do is to combine these two vectors into one vector if one name begins with the exact same name, so the output looks like this:

```
Ketchup Chips
1        1
1        0
0        1
1        0
```

what should I do?

Comment: Is this a data.frame or a matrix? Please provide a slightly larger example using `dput`. Maybe with two or three column categories.

Comment: What if there are three columns? You want to combine the three? and by combine you mean `sum` right?

Comment: it is a matrix for recommendation system. I'd like to reduce the size of the matrix since some products can be replaced easily. I want them to be one product not three different ones

Answer (score 3):

I believe this does what you want. At least with the dataset you have provided it does. And it doesn't depend on hard coded column names.

With the data as read by the code in @MKR answer:

```
nms <- names(df)
inx <- which(sapply(seq_along(nms), function(i) any(grepl(paste0("^", nms[i]), nms[-i]))))
result <- sapply(inx, function(i) rowSums(df[, grep(nms[i], nms)]))
colnames(result) <- nms[inx]
result
#     Ketchup Chips
#[1,]       1     1
#[2,]       1     0
#[3,]       0     1
#[4,]       1     0
```

Answer (score 2):

An option using `dplyr::coalesce` can be reached after converting your matrix to `data.frame`. Also, cell having value as `0` should be changed to `NA` to apply `coalesce`.

```
library(dplyr)
# First change matrix to data.frame. The same data is created in data.frame 
# so this step can be skipped
df <- as.data.frame(df)

# Replace 0 with NA
df[df==0] <- NA
```

**Option#1:** If column names are less and known then once approach as

```
bind_cols(Chips = coalesce(!!!select(df, starts_with("Chips"))), 
          Ketchup = coalesce(!!!select(df, starts_with("Ketchup"))) )
# # A tibble: 4 x 2
#   Chips Ketchup
#   <int>   <int>
# 1     1       1
# 2    NA       1
# 3     1      NA
# 4    NA       1
```

**Option#2:** The generic approach could be written as:

```
overlapName <- names(df)[mapply(function(x)sum(str_detect(names(df),x)), names(df)) >1]
library(stringr)

mapply(function(x)coalesce(!!!select(df, starts_with(x))), overlapName)
#      Ketchup Chips
# [1,]       1     1
# [2,]       1    NA
# [3,]      NA     1
# [4,]       1    NA
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"Ketchup  Ketchupwithgarlic  Ketchupspicy Chips Chipsorganic
0               1               0         0      1
1               0               0         0      0
0               0               0         1      0
1               0               0         0      0",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks! But what if I want to do it for all products that I have in my matrix. For example: apple and applegreen, icecream and icecreamchocolate

Comment: @nurma_a I provided an option so that it can be done for a set. Now we need to scale it up to cover all columns.

Comment: @RonakShah I agree with you. We have to device a way to find find common unique names which are repeated in other columns.

Comment: @RonakShah I have updated my answer to include a generic way of detecting columns being overlapped and use that as input.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another base R alternative. I think Rui Barrades's answer is probably better, but it can be helpful to see multiple approaches.

```
# save column names
cnms <- colnames(myMat)
# build a matrix that groups on column names using col and grepl
grps <- col(diag(length(cnms))) * sapply(cnms[order(cnms)], grepl, x=cnms)
# run through the groups and perform rowSums to collapse groups into one column
sapply(split(seq_len(ncol(myMat)), 
             colnames(grps)[apply(grps, 1, FUN=function(x) min(x[x != 0]))]),
       function(y) rowSums(myMat[, y]))
```

This returns

```
     Chips Ketchup
[1,]     1       1
[2,]     0       1
[3,]     1       0
[4,]     0       1
```

**data**

```
myMat <-
structure(c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), .Dim = 4:5, .Dimnames = list(NULL, 
    c("Ketchup", "Ketchupwithgarlic", "Ketchupspicy", "Chips", 
    "Chipsorganic")))
```